# cordova plugin for file path to base64 string

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, firebase-storage

Plugin to be used for encoding base64 of any file (image, video etc.)

Example (In android device) when we capture video using ionic2 native plugin that returns video local URI that required to convert in base64. So that could be stored in datastore like Firebase-storage.

---

I tried https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64

But returns empty string, without any error.

Any other plugin available in cordova / Ionic 2 native apis?

Comment: Did you tried out this link of converting using file plugin - http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova

Comment: Yes, it does nothing, not working for video.

Comment: Does your video works in the chrome browser? If so, you should try the crosswalk-plugin for getting a more modern javascript engine in your project.